# django time does not work correctly

Tags: python, django, linux, time

I have a django application and I Setting up Django and my web server with uWSGI and nginx. I have a function that sets access time for my file, this is my function:

```
from shutil import move
from time import mktime
from os import utime
def spool(self, time=None):
    if time:
        try:
            time = mktime(time.timetuple())
            utime(path(self.tempdir) / path(self.filename), (time, time))
        except (error, AttributeError, OverflowError, ValueError):
            raise InvalidTimeError

    try:
        move(path(self.tempdir) / path(self.filename),
                path(self.spool_dir) / path(self.filename))
    except IOError:
        raise NoSpoolPermissionError
```

when I run this function with python command the access time is correct:

```
root@demo:~# stat /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/tmp_4BmDa.call 
  File: `/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/tmp_4BmDa.call'
  Size: 56          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 561550      Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-08-21 11:27:30.000000000 +0430
Modify: 2013-08-21 11:27:30.000000000 +0430
Change: 2013-08-21 11:24:00.142143170 +0430
 Birth: -
```

but when I run the function in my django application the output is:

```
root@demo:~# stat /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/tmp_4BmDa.call 
  File: `/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/tmp_4BmDa.call'
  Size: 242         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 561542      Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-08-21 21:15:00.000000000 +0430
Modify: 2013-08-21 21:15:00.000000000 +0430
Change: 2013-08-21 11:44:42.982093206 +0430
 Birth: -
```

as you can see the access time is <<2013-08-21 21:15:00>> but It must be <<2013-08-21 11:44:42>> and I have no idea what happend.
linux date  command output is:

```
root@demo:~# date
Wed Aug 21 11:44:55 IRDT 2013
```

and python datetime output:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 21, 11, 45, 57, 886360)
```

Comment: Check timezone setting in webserver conf and django settings set to appropriate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check timezone setting in webserver conf and django settings set to appropriate value.

Time in wsgi/django environment will be affected by timezone settings in these config files.